# What does it mean for a plane wave to be an eigenstate of a 3D vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

> Show that $$ \phi_p(r) = \left(\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^{3/2}e^{ip\cdot r/\hbar}$$
>   is an eigenstate of p, where p and r are 3D vectors.

I'm unclear on what the final equation I'm trying to get to should look like. I thought that the final result would be showing that $\phi_p$ is equal to $ap$, with $a$ being some constant.

However, I also thought that a vector is an eigenvector for a particular matrix/operator, but I'm not sure what should be the operator for which p and $\phi_p$ are eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certain that you're misreading the text, or that it got mangled in some other way, and that it should really read

> Show that $$ \phi_{\vec p}(\vec r) =\left(\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^{3/2}e^{i\vec p\cdot \vec r/\hbar}$$
>   is an eigenstate of $\hat{\vec p}$, where $\vec p$ and $\vec r$ are 3D vectors,

and where
$$
\hat{\vec p} = -i\hbar \nabla
$$
is the quantum-mechanical momentum operator. You're being asked to show that $\hat{\vec p} \phi_{\vec p} = -i\hbar \nabla\phi_{\vec p}(\vec r)$ is a multiple of $\phi_{\vec p}(\vec r)$.

If that's not the case, then you should double-check with whoever set you that exercise, or look for a better textbook. The exercise text as you've quoted it makes no sense other than as a mangled version of the quote in this answer.

Comment: I think I understand it now. I previously thought that p and r were arbitrary vectors, not momentum and position. Is it correct that I get that the answer is a 3D vector  times the wave function or is that wrong in form (I believe it should be a constant)?